# Facebook Iframe tab - Show the native photo lightbox?

Tags: facebook, iframe

I'm making Iframe app for Facebook's tab page. It has photos listing pulled from an Album.

Is there a way to show the native lightbox / popup for commenting. The one like shown in the picture below:

[image]

From the Graph API, I got the photo ID and all the data. Is there a way to initiate this event?

I can't seem to find the right term to Google it. I found an answer from 2011 saying it's impossible. Is it possible now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I have found, there's no way of doing this.

So, the simplest alternative is to open the photo in new browser tab.

Your link:

```
<a data-url="<?php echo $photo_url; ?>">
  ...
</a>
```

Javascript (using JQuery):

```
$("[data-url]").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).data("url");
  window.open(url);
});
```